# How do I drop the right index on a left merge from the results?

Tags: pandas, merge

In the below example, I can get the merge to run correctly, but how do I not have the second index print as well?  Do I have to add a separate line of code:

```
df_merge = df_merge.drop(columns='cities')
```

Can't I choose which columns I want to merge into the left dataset?  What if df2 had 30 columns and I only want 10 of them?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "city": ['new york','chicago', 'orlando','ottawa'],
    "humidity": [35,69,79,99]
})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "cities": ['new york', 'chicago', 'toronto'],
    "temp": [1, 6, -35]
})

df_merge = df1.merge(df2, left_on='city', right_on='cities', how='left')
print(df_merge)

**output**

   index      city  humidity    cities  temp
0      0  new york        35  new york   1.0
1      1   chicago        69   chicago   6.0
2      2   orlando        79       NaN   NaN
3      3    ottawa        99       NaN   NaN
```

Comment: add `left_index=True`?

Comment: You can always subset the merge. so like `df1.merge(df2[['col1, 'col2', 'col3']])` would just merge with those 3 columns from df2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `merge`

Change the name of the column first

```
df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'cities': 'city'}), 'left')

       city  humidity  temp
0  new york        35   1.0
1   chicago        69   6.0
2   orlando        79   NaN
3    ottawa        99   NaN
```

---

If you need to explicitly state what you're merging on:

```
df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'cities': 'city'}), how='left', on='city')
```

---

### `join`

set the index of the right side first
`'left'` is default.

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('cities'), 'city')

       city  humidity  temp
0  new york        35   1.0
1   chicago        69   6.0
2   orlando        79   NaN
3    ottawa        99   NaN
```

---

### `map`

Make a dictionary.

```
df1.assign(temp=df1.city.map(dict(df2.values)))

       city  humidity  temp
0  new york        35   1.0
1   chicago        69   6.0
2   orlando        79   NaN
3    ottawa        99   NaN
```

---

Less cute, more explicit

```
df1.assign(temp=df1.city.map(dict(df2.set_index('cities').temp)))
```

Comment: @caddie I'm glad you like it.  Feel free to upvote any and all answers that you found helpful.  And if you don't mind accept one of the answers as well.  Thanks.  (Accepting is the checkmark, upvoting is the up-arrow)

Comment: Quick follow up question, what if my right table has 30 columns and I only want to pull in 5 of them?  How do you chose which columns get pulled in?

Comment: `df1.join(df2.set_index('cities')[list_of_column_names], 'city')`

Answer (score 2):

`set_index` and assign

```
df1=df1.set_index('city');df2=df2.set_index('cities')
df1['temp']=df2.temp
df1.reset_index()

Out[595]: 
       city  humidity  temp
0  new york        35   1.0
1   chicago        69   6.0
2   orlando        79   NaN
3    ottawa        99   NaN
```

Comment: @caddie yw : -) happy coding